# Seg fault creating archive for swift app

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

At my wits end trying to archive a Swift iOS app for upload to the app store.  The archive is failing with this error:

clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11

clang: error: linker command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)

The app builds fine for development, and this is for an app that I've successfully archived/uploaded before.  One thing that's changed is that my Apple developer account was migrated to a company account from an individual.  I read somewhere that this issue can be solved by regenerating certificates/provisioning profiles, which I've done and are associated with the new team account.  My question is whether anyone has run into this issue before in the context of migrating a individual to team account, and if people have any ideas for how to address this given that I've already tried new certificates/profiles.

Comment: Segmentation fault while compiling Swift has meant a Swift compiler error for me. Maybe you have a different config for archiving or you do config based preprocessing? I've usually just commented sutff out line by line to get to the culprit. But if nothing has changed then it is pretty difficult.

Comment: @juhan_h see my answer below, the answer was simply changing "Enable Bitcode" to false

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after 24 hours of playing with certificates/profiles/cocoapods that I'll never get back, the solution was simply to go into "Build Settings" for the project and set "Enable Bitcode" to false.

Hopefully this helps anyone else who runs into this issue.